# attachMovie() AS2 function in AS3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, actionscript-2

So I have a movieclip named world in the bottom left of the screen which is suppose to "spawn" all of the block movieclips to fill the screen. The block movieclip is called block and exists only in the library.
worldWidth, blockSize, and worldHeight are just numbers.

Normally, in AS2 I could just do this:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= blockWidth; x++) {
    for (var y = 1; y <= blockHeight; y++) {
        temp = world.attachMovie("block","bX" + x + "Y" + y, world.getNextHighestDepth());
        temp._x = x*blockSize-blockSize/2;
        temp._y = -y*blockSize+blockSize/2;
    }
}
```

and all would be perfect..

But I'm using adobe air for android and AS3 is forced. AS3 is missing the "attachMovie()" function. I've searched for solutions but they are too situation-specific for me to understand.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've tried to start on this using the answer provided and here's what I have:

```
stop();
import flash.display.MovieClip;
var blockSize:Number = 32;
var worldWidth:Number = 800/blockSize;
var worldHeight:Number = 480/blockSize;
render();
function render(){
       for (var x = 1; x<=worldWidth; x++) {
        for (var y = 1; y<=worldHeight; y++) {
            var Block = new block();
            Block.name = "BX" + x + "Y" + y;
            Block.x = x*blockSize-blockSize/2;
            Block.y = -y*blockSize+blockSize/2;
            Block.gotoAndStop(3);
            world.addChild(Block);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the screen flashes constantly. I have no clue why.

EDIT: Really silly mistake, I forgot to stop() the frames inside the block MovieClip.

Question answered, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the properties of library item and set a class name you want(such as 'Block') to export it as.

Then you can make a new block like this:

```
var block = new Block();
block.x = 20;
block.y = 5;
world.addChild(block);
```

Any DisplayObject added via addChild() will always be put at the top layer.

Since your're new to AS3. You'll want to learn the methods of the [DisplayObject class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) any MovieClip or Sprite(an mc without any timeline) inherit these methods.